# Jquery Ajax - Problemas ao renderizar gráficos utilizando requisição jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, aplicação-web, graphics

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que tem como objetivo gerar relatórios mensais de algumas informações vindas do aplicativo mobile. Como tenho pouca experiencia com Jquery estou com dificuldade em carregar as informações no gráfico. Estou utilizando a API https://www.amcharts.com para gerar os gráficos. Minha pagina html o usuário irá escolher o determinado mes que ele queira ver os dados e clicar em carregar. Ao clicar o gráfico contendo as informações de quantidade de palhetas instaladas e quantidade de palhetas positivas por bairro serão carregados no gráfico.

segue imagem do grafico de maneira estatica. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde tem os paises serao os bairro que foram instaladas as palhetas.

O meu model esta assim:

```
@Entity
public class Palheta extends GenericModel{

@Required
@Expose
public String codigo;

public String ovos;
@Required
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date data_instalacao;
@Required
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date data_coleta;
@Expose
public String observacao;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="endereco_id")
@Expose
public Endereco endereco;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="agente_id")
@Expose
public Agente agente;
@Expose
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;
@Expose
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status situacao;
@Expose
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status_palheta;
@Expose
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status statusMsg;
public Palheta() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
    statusMsg = Status.NAO_LIDA;
}
}
```

Minha pagina html onde sao gerados os graficos esta assim:

```
<section class="forms">
<form action="@{Services.relatorios}" method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label>Selecione o mês:</label> <select id="mes" class="custom-select mb-3 mr-sm-3 mb-sm-0"
                    name="valor">
                    <option selected>Selecione...</option>
                    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
                    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
                    <option value="3">Março</option>
                    <option value="4">Abril</option>
                    <option value="5">Maio</option>
                    <option value="6">Junho</option>
                    <option value="7">Julho</option>
                    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                    <option value="9">Setembro</option>
                    <option value="10">Outubro</option>
                    <option value="11">Novembro</option>
                    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
                </select>

                <button id="btRelUm" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Carregar</button>
            </div>
<!-- Bar Chart   -->
                        <div class="chart col-lg-9 col-12">
                            <div id="chartdiv2" class="chartdiv float"></div>
                        </div>
```

O script jquery para gerar o grafico:

```
$(function() {
        $("#btRelUm").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "/relatorios/palhetasPositivas",
              data: {
                  valor: $("#mes").val()
              }
            }).done(function(data) {
            /**
             * PRIMEIRO chart
             */
            var chart = AmCharts
                    .makeChart(
                            "chartdiv2",
                            {
                                "theme" : "light",
                                "type" : "serial",
                                "dataProvider" : [ {
                                    "country" : "USA",
                                    "year2004" : 3.5,
                                    "year2005" : 4.2
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "UK",
                                    "year2004" : 1.7,
                                    "year2005" : 3.1
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "Canada",
                                    "year2004" : 2.8,
                                    "year2005" : 2.9
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "Japan",
                                    "year2004" : 2.6,
                                    "year2005" : 2.3
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "France",
                                    "year2004" : 1.4,
                                    "year2005" : 2.1
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "Brazil",
                                    "year2004" : 2.6,
                                    "year2005" : 4.9
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "Russia",
                                    "year2004" : 6.4,
                                    "year2005" : 7.2
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "India",
                                    "year2004" : 8,
                                    "year2005" : 7.1
                                }, {
                                    "country" : "China",
                                    "year2004" : 9.9,
                                    "year2005" : 10.1
                                } ],
                                "valueAxes" : [ {
                                    "stackType" : "3d",
                                    "unit" : "%",
                                    "position" : "left",
                                    "title" : "Palhetas instaladas - Amarelo / Palhetas positivas - Verde",
                                } ],
                                "startDuration" : 1,
                                "graphs" : [
                                        {
                                            "balloonText" : "Palhetas instaladas <b>[[value]]</b>",
                                            "fillAlphas" : 0.9,
                                            "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
                                            "title" : "2004",
                                            "type" : "column",
                                            "valueField" : "year2004"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "balloonText" : "Palhetas positivas  <b>[[value]]</b>",
                                            "fillAlphas" : 0.9,
                                            "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
                                            "title" : "2005",
                                            "type" : "column",
                                            "valueField" : "year2005"
                                        } ],
                                "plotAreaFillAlphas" : 0.1,
                                "depth3D" : 60,
                                "angle" : 20,
                                "categoryField" : "country",
                                "categoryAxis" : {
                                    "gridPosition" : "start"
                                },
                                "titles" : [ {
                                    "text" : "Relatório mensal por bairro"
                                } ],
                                "export" : {
                                    "enabled" : true,
                                    "menu" : []
                                }
                            });
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

                });

            });
        });
```

O meu controller Services reponsável por criar o serviço que alimentará os graficos.

```
public static void palhetasInstaladas(Integer valor) {
    long palCount = Palheta.count("status = ? and situacao = ? or situacao =? and month(data_instalacao) = ?", Status.ATIVO,  Status.INSTALADA, Status.COLETADA, valor);

    if (valor == null || valor < 1 ||valor > 12) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ERRO!!!");          
    }
    renderJSON(palCount);
}

public static void palhetasPositivas(Integer valor) {
    long positivasCount = Palheta.count("status = ? and status_palheta =? and month(data_instalacao) =?", Status.ATIVO,
            Status.POSITIVA, valor);

    if (valor == null || valor < 1 ||valor > 12) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ERRO!!!");          
    }
    renderJSON(positivasCount);
}
```

ALguem pode me ajudar a implementar esses gráficos?

Comment: Java (principalmente para servidores) não é meu "forte". Quais os dados retornados em `done( function(data) )` (no JavaScript) ?

Comment: @Valdeir quero pegar o bairro e a quantidade de palhetas instaladas naquele bairro